# When running webpack, in my webpack.config.js, all values of process.env are set to undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to set up a `webpack.config.js` that detects the value of `NODE_ENV` and then minifies the output (or not) based on that value.  It was always outputting minified versions, so I ran `node-debug webpack` to see what was going on.

In `webpack.config.js`, `process.env` is defined as an `Object` with a bunch of values, but all the properties listed are `undefined`, and `NODE_ENV` isn't even one of the values of `process.env`.

Ideas?

#### A little context

I'm creating a batch script to run two instances of webpack to create `.js` and `.min.js` files simultaneously:

```
set NODE_ENV=development
start webpack -c --progress -w

set NODE_ENV=production
start webpack -c --progress -w
```

However, to debug it, I simply ran separate commands:

```
set NODE_ENV=development
node-debug webpack -c --progress
```

Thanks!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm running Windows 8

Comment: Ok. I don't have Windows available atm but you could try something like `set NODE_ENV=development&&webpack -c --progress -w`. Though that said it could be something more fundamental. If you can't get it to work, consider dropping Webpack out of the equation while testing and see what it looks against pure Node.js.

Comment: Any luck with this? Did you get useful debug information outside of Webpack?